# How to update Tomcat 7.0.54 to 7.0.69

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7

I want to update a Tomcat 7.0.54 server to version 7.0.69. It's running on Redhat Enterprise Linux (RHEL).

[The migration guide](http://tomcat.apache.org/migration-7.html#Upgrading_7.0.x) only mentions the changes in some of the configuration files, but says nothing over how to upgrade. Is it just a matter of stopping Tomcat, replace the files, start Tomcat? So what do I need to do?

Comment: Generally TC is deployed as a .tar.gz/.zip (with the version number). In my experience, one does not "upgrade" so much as unzip the new version, update configuration files, stop the old tomcat, start the new one (app deployment varies; might be just copying the .war file; might be uploading, etc.). The ports are in the configuration file, it should then change to use the new one. If you have a particular directory naming for TC, then update the directory names if needed. We use symlinks to avoid needing to rename directories and revert easily if need be (as we are on RHEL6 so no docker yet).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before any update - make backup.

Next action depends of how initially you set up tomcat. If it was installed from package manager - use package manager to update it with

```
# yum update tomcat
```

Installation script should take care about start/stop/backup changed files. It usually does.

If you install it manually - create separate dir, unpack fresh tomcat in it, and follow application deployment plan, as if you deploying application on fresh tomcat. Deployment plan should describe what you should change in which configuration files.

If you do not have any deployment plan, it mean your application do not required any changes in configs or your developers is lazy.

So, manually check candidates for changes.

- `conf` directory. All files may have changes, but most likely: tomcat-users.xml, web.xml, server.xml, content.xml, catalina.properties. Check ssl connector settings for keystore location (if ssl connector configured).
- `bin` directory. Maybe catalina.sh (someone may add config variables here) and setenv.sh ( or here ). setenv.sh may not exists.
- `lib` directory. Check for any non-standart jar (custom filters, jdbc drivers, etc)

If everything OK (no changes or changes was reflected in new installation), install you application in new tomcat. After that stop old tomcat and start new.
I recommend also create simlink to working version and all scripts run with that simlink.

for example old tomcat run in `/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.54`, new in `/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.69`, create simplink 
`ln -s /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.69 /opt/tomcat` and run tomcat with /opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh or /opt/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh start or whatever command you are using.

Comment: how to install specific version of tomcat using yum like `tomcat-7-v7.0.109/`